# What's the best way to represent an editable checksum index of a filesystem?

Tags: sql, database, checksum, flat-file

Given any file, I want to identify duplicate files with identical checksums. I simply want to print a textual list of the duplicates to my terminal, so running a full desktop-search indexer would be absolute overkill.

To do what I want, I need to associatively store two pieces of information:

1. "[This file] has <*XYZ* checksum>", for any *file*
2. "[Here are all the files] for <*XYZ* checksum>", for any *checksum*

The catch is that I need the database to be editable so that, as I move data around - and notify the script managing the DB - it can keep up with the changes. There are two approaches I've thought of to do this.

One would be to use an offset-based flatfile index, but I would need to implement a fragmentation scheme so I could extend directory representations with new files as data was moved around, without having to constantly bitshift the entire file forwards and backwards to accommodate the data restructuring.
While not impossible for me to do, this would be sufficiently nontrivial that I would have concerns about database consistency and integrity, and since I'd be making decisions about whether to delete data off the back of this information I'd be playing with such an implementation for a while before I settled with using it.

I have no experience with using traditional databases, but I'm imagining SQL can probably achieve what I'm trying to do with significantly more ease than implementing an entire storage framework myself. If this is an option, where would be a good place to start? I'd tentatively theorize that I could create two tables: the first would list each checksum in the first (primary) column and a NUL-separated string of each file this checksum matched in the 2nd column; the second table would list the full path to the file in the first/primary column, and its checksum in the second. Updates to this system would require I simply modify a column in two tables, and be significantly simpler/easier than the method suggested above.

Comment: You need just one table and storing such data as well as reporting on it is not a problem. The question is: how would you trigger its updates.  You will need to watch every directory for any changes and when it happens run your script that will update the database (calculating a new checksum when necessary).

Comment: Updating is not an issue at all; I will be creating aliases for `mv`, `cp`, `rm`, `cd`, etc that will tell my script when I change directories and move/copy/remove files - because I'll be using this exclusively from the shell. I'm soley baffled at exactly how to store and maintain the DB/index.

Comment: Simple table with 2 columns: `file` and `checksum`.  SQL will do the rest.  If you index your database on both fields it should be pretty efficient. If you want to track file renames / moves as such (and not treat them as delete + add) you will also need `file_id` as a unique key.

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could index multiple fields, cool. How would the two columns work? A file is only ever going to have one checksum but a given checksum could match any number of files, so I need some kind of one-to-many relationship implementation. I also don't fully understand unique keying, and don't mind renames being delete+add (essentially what my flatfile system was going to do under the hood).

Comment: Have a look at [this **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e84/1). It uses MySQL but the same can be handled by any RDBMS.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I had absolutely no idea it could be that simple. *shakes head* wow :) Convert this to an answer, if you like, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a database table with 2 columns: `File` and `ChecSum`.  File (presented as full path) is `UNIQUE` by nature and can be used as `UNIQUE INDEX`.  You may still want to add `ID` field (integer code) as `PRIMARY KEY`, especially if you want to treat `moving` or `renaming` as a single operation and not to split it into `delete` followed by `create`.

In MySQL (used as an example) you will have something like this (without `ID` column):

**[DDL and DML](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Language/Definitions:_what_are_DDL,_DML_and_DQL%3F)**:

```
CREATE TABLE Files
    (`File` varchar(16), `CheckSum` int)
;

ALTER TABLE Files ADD UNIQUE INDEX (File), ADD INDEX (CheckSum);

INSERT INTO Files
    (`File`, `CheckSum`)
VALUES
    ('\dir1\file1', 56789),
    ('\dir2\file2', 77777),
    ('\dir3\dir4\file9', 56789),
    ('\dirA\file1', 12345)
;
```

**[DOL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Language/Definitions:_what_are_DDL,_DML_and_DQL%3F)**:

```
-- All files
SELECT * 
FROM Files;

-- All files with checksum = 56789
SELECT * 
FROM Files
WHERE checksum = 56789;

-- File name '\dirA\file1'
SELECT *
FROM Files 
WHERE file = '\dirA\file1';
```

[**SQL Fiddle** with the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e84/1)